# combine two commands that swap white for black into one

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, transparency, mogrify

I have a large number of images that are white with transparent backgrounds, and I would like to make them black with transparent backgrounds. It's simple enough to do with GIMP or BIMP, but with thousands of images, command-line seems a better way to go. 
In ImageMagick, I've found that the following two commands do what I want:

```
mogrify -alpha set -channel RGBA -background black -flatten +repage -negate *.png
mogrify -alpha set -channel RGBA -transparent white *.png
```

However, I'd rather not make two passes. I've tried to combine them a number of different ways:

`mogrify -alpha set -channel RGBA -background black -flatten +repage -negate +repage -transparent white *.png`

`mogrify -alpha set -channel RGBA -background black -flatten +repage -negate -alpha set -channel RGBA -transparent white *.png`

`mogrify -alpha set -channel RGBA -background black -flatten +repage -negate +repage -alpha set -channel RGBA -transparent white *.png`

as well as a couple other permutations of the same ideas. All of them result in a purely black image. What am I missing?

Is there an easier way to invert black and white or at least convert white to black, but leaving the alpha layer untouched?

```
mogrify -negate *.png
```

converts white to transparent and transparent to white, and

```
mogrify -fill black -opaque white *.png
```

leaves behind messy white edges.

Comment: An idea of the platform/operating system may help, _your batch-file tag suggests MS-DOS, OS/2 or Windows_.

Comment: Please provide a couple of sample input images and corresponding output images - individually, not montaged into a single image.

Comment: Also, what OS are you using and what's the objection to two passes?

Comment: windows, and hundreds of thousands of images to process—cut down from 8 hours to 4 hours

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick you can do:

```
mogrify -format png -fill "rgba(0,0,0,1)" -opaque "rgba(255,255,255,1)" *.png
```

If your white is not perfectly white, then add -fuzz XX%

```
mogrify -format png -fuzz 5% -fill "rgba(0,0,0,1)" -opaque "rgba(255,255,255,1)" *.png
```

The issue is that you need to specify alpha values in your colors, since your image has transparency. Thus use rgba(r,g,b,a) values (note the a) or use hex values with #RRGGBBAA

If using IM 7, then mogrify is replace with magick mogrify

Here is an example using convert. I created a white image with transparency elsewhere from the logo: image.

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/transparency_invert/logot.png

Then ran

```
convert logot.png -fill "rgba(0,0,0,1)" -opaque "rgba(255,255,255,1)" logot_invert.png
```

Which returns black where the input was white and keeps the transparency unchanged.

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/transparency_invert/logot_invert.png

Is this not what you want?

Comment: even with the fuzz, it still does the same thing as -fill black -opaque white. the part that isn't black is white, and i'm guessing the fuzz percentages work by color distance. isn't there something that does the same as gimp's gimp-invert?

Comment: I guess I do not understand the issue. Can you post an example image and explain what you want to happen or show a result from using GIMP?

Comment: CONTINUED: see my edits to my post above with an example. Is that not what you want? If not please post your input and GIMP output.

Comment: [Example](http://www.matthewmorrone.com/example.png)

each column contains the same picture, just with different backgrounds.
I'm starting with an image like the first, and want the image to look like the second, which is what the two commands listed at the beginning allow. columns 7 and 8 are the results of your suggestions. do you see what I mean with the white edges?

Comment: Can you please post individually your input images and what you want for the output images. I cannot work with a composite. It does not preserve the transparency. I need separate files. What do each of your columns represent? Which are your desired results? I do not understand or see the white edges. I do not see the difference between your results (col 2) and my results (col 7)

Comment: [here](http://matthewmorrone.com/example/) are separate image file examples

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is the following in ImageMagick. Just a guess until I can see your actual input files.

```
mogrify -format png -alpha off -negate -alpha on *.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick, try

```
mogrify -alpha off -negate -alpha on *.png
```

This turns off the alpha channel inverts the black and white and then turns on the original alpha channel.

As a test, I did

```
convert aircon.png -alpha off -negate -alpha on aircon_fred.png
```

[image]

The equivalent of your two mogrify command is

```
mogrify -background black -alpha background -alpha off -negate -transparent white *.png
```

I had to replace your -flatten with the equivalent since one needs to reset the compose method to over afterwards for the -transparent to work. But mogrify does not accept -compose over.

As a simple test, I did

```
convert aircon.png -background black -flatten -negate -transparent white aircon_fred2.png
```

[image]

Another method similar to the first is just to make the whole underlying image black and keep the alpha channel.

```
mogrify -alpha off -fill black -opaque white -alpha on *.png
```

Again as a test, I did

```
convert aircon.png -alpha off -fill black -opaque white -alpha on aircon_fred3.png
```

[image]

However, my first method should give better antialiasing, since it keeps your original alpha channel. Your method will recreate the alpha via -transparent white and will have more stair-stepped aliasing.

Comment: This didn't work for me but `mogrify -alpha deactivate -negate *.png` did

Comment: You must be on ImageMagick 7 and not Imagemagic 6. If so, use `magick mogrify -alpha deactivate -negate *.png`